# Code Compiles in Windows but Doesn't in Linux

Tags: miktex, texlive, texmaker, linux

I'm currently in the process of standing up a Linux machine, and one of the things I'm trying to get running is Texmaker.  I've got that installed as well as the full texlive package on the new Linux machine.  On the old Windows machine, I'm running Texmaker on top of MikTeX.

The problem that I'm experiencing is with a very large TeX file (my partially completed dissertation).  The file compiles perfectly on the Windows machine, but the same code will not compile on the Linux machine, throwing this error instead:

```
Runaway argument?
{preli
! File ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel.
<inserted text>
\par
l.80 \begin{document}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
\openout1 = `Test6.aux'.
```

Since the exact same code compiles on the Windows machine, I think that there must be something wrong with my Linux installation, or perhaps with the encoding of the TeX file I'm attempting to compile.

Have any of you run into similar problems?  If so, how did you resolve it?  If additional logs from the failed compilation would be helpful (or other code snippets), I'm happy to provide those.

**EDIT**

Here's the beginning code of the document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=intro,title=Index to the Introduction and Prefaces]
\makeindex[name=name,title=Index of Names]
\makeindex[name=subj,title=Index of Subjects]
\makeindex[name=for,title=Index of Foreign Terms]

\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D},noend, noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black!50!black},
    citecolor={black!50!black},
    urlcolor={black!80!black}
}

\sloppy

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}

\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}

\newfam\hebfam
\font\tmp=rcjhbltx at10pt \textfont\hebfam=\tmp
\font\tmp=rcjhbltx at7pt  \scriptfont\hebfam=\tmp
\font\tmp=rcjhbltx at5pt  \scriptscriptfont\hebfam=\tmp

\edef\declfam{\ifcase\hebfam 
 0\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\fi}

\mathchardef\aleph  = "0\declfam 27
\mathchardef\beth   = "0\declfam 62
\mathchardef\gimel  = "0\declfam 67
\mathchardef\daleth = "0\declfam 64
\mathchardef\he     = "0\declfam 68
\mathchardef\vau    = "0\declfam 77
\mathchardef\zayin  = "0\declfam 7A
\mathchardef\cheth  = "0\declfam 78
\mathchardef\teth   = "0\declfam 54
\mathchardef\yod    = "0\declfam 79
\mathchardef\kaph   = "0\declfam 6B
\mathchardef\kaphfinal  = "0\declfam 4B
\mathchardef\lamed  = "0\declfam 6C
\mathchardef\mem    = "0\declfam 6D
\mathchardef\memfinal   = "0\declfam 4D
\mathchardef\nun    = "0\declfam 6E
\mathchardef\nunfinal   = "0\declfam 4E
\mathchardef\samekh = "0\declfam 73
\mathchardef\ayin   = "0\declfam 60
\mathchardef\pe     = "0\declfam 70
\mathchardef\pefinal    = "0\declfam 50
\mathchardef\tzaddi = "0\declfam 76
\mathchardef\tzaddifinal    = "0\declfam 5A
\mathchardef\qoph   = "0\declfam 71
\mathchardef\resh   = "0\declfam 72
\mathchardef\shin   = "0\declfam 98 % 98 is hexa code of shin
\mathchardef\tau    = "0\declfam 74

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps an encoding problem? Did you use `utf8` on both machines?

Comment: Just checked both machines, encoding is UTF-8 across the board.

Comment: You should treat your Linux machine better - fancy standing it up! Can you blame it for feeling irritable?

Comment: @Bernard Line endings? What would be used on Windows? @ OP Can you create a minimal example which produces the error? It does not seem to be getting very far before failing.

Comment: @cfr: PCs use CR+LF, but I'm not sure this is a problem: modern editors are able to understand both.

Comment: @cfr I'm not able to reproduce the error with a minimal example.  Starting from the beginning, I've moved the `\end{document}` statement paragraph by paragraph until I hit the 3,000s.  Up until then, the document compiles.  But midway through the 3,000s, it will compile sometimes and throw this error other times; and past a certain line it won't compile at all.  There's nothing special about this point-of-no-return from what I can tell; it's just a regular `\par{...}` section.

Comment: `\par` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  What I meant was that all of the preceding paragraphs were done with `\par`, so there's nothing different about this particular spot in the document.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded last (unless you are loading something like `cleveref` or `bidi`). Are you really typesetting an entire dissertation with `\sloppy`?

Comment: But `\par` does not take an argument. You should not usually use it in the body of your document at all - usually, it is clearer to leave a blank line. But you can use `\par` if you prefer. But it does not take an argument. `\par{something}` is just `\par something`. It doesn't make sense at all to give it an argument. Regardless of how often you've done it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on `\par`.  Would my use of an argument with it be causing this error in Linux but not Windows?  Moving `hyperref` to the end of the `\usepackage` list still throws the same error too.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that the same file compiles on the Windows machine and not the Linux one and you are sure you are using exactly the same command line for compilation (less any differences due to MikTeX/TeX Live) and, in addition, you've deleted all generated files on both machines and are still really, really sure, then put `\listfiles` before document class and compare the output on the two boxes. Post the two lots of output if you aren't sure.

Comment: @Psychonaut418 I wouldn't have thought so. The curly brackets don't make it an argument. It is like saying `\small{something}`. It is wrong, because the author clearly thinks `\small` takes an argument, when it doesn't, so it will probably give unexpected output. But it isn't technically wrong from TeX's point of view. It just creates an unnecessary TeX group for no purpose.

Comment: The files are definitely exactly the same; no question about that.  I'm not compiling on the command line in either case though.  In both, I'm using the Texmaker GUI with PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Compile on the command line to troubleshoot. That way, you can sometimes get more information by pressing `h` when the error occurs.

Comment: Same error message kills the process compiling from the command line:

Runaway argument?
{preli 
! File ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.79 \begin{document}

Comment: Did you place all of your text in an ordinary text editor, and search for the number of occurences of opening and closing braces? Same with \begingrouo and \endgroup.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the aux files and recompiling? Are you running the same package versions on both systems. Exactly which latex installation are you using on Linux?

Comment: `\@newl@bel` indicates a problem with a `\newlabel` definition in the aux-file. Open the aux, search for the `preli ` mentioned in the error message and try to figure out, why the argument is fault. As you have a windows aux which compiles you can compare the two.